How to track a specific click on a specific svg
In general, what is the problem, when you click on the arrow, only the first of all turns over, the rest do not react
I need that when I click on one of the arrows, the class is added specifically to it
My html code:
<div class="faq-question-container">
    <div class="faq-question">
        <font>С какими формами организаций вы работаете и заключаете договоры?</font>
        <svg class="arrow" width="24" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M10.9393 13.0608C11.5251 13.6465 12.4749 13.6465 13.0607 13.0608L22.6066 3.51482C23.1924 2.92903 23.1924 1.97928 22.6066 1.3935C22.0208 0.807712 21.0711 0.807712 20.4853 1.3935L12 9.87878L3.51472 1.3935C2.92893 0.807711 1.97919 0.807711 1.3934 1.3935C0.807612 1.97928 0.807612 2.92903 1.3934 3.51482L10.9393 13.0608ZM10.5 12L10.5 12.0001L13.5 12.0001L13.5 12L10.5 12Z" fill="black"/>
        </svg>
        <p class="faq-answer">- С любыми</p>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="faq-question-container">
    <div class="faq-question">
        <font>С какими формами организаций вы работаете и заключаете договоры?</font>
        <svg class="arrow" width="24" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M10.9393 13.0608C11.5251 13.6465 12.4749 13.6465 13.0607 13.0608L22.6066 3.51482C23.1924 2.92903 23.1924 1.97928 22.6066 1.3935C22.0208 0.807712 21.0711 0.807712 20.4853 1.3935L12 9.87878L3.51472 1.3935C2.92893 0.807711 1.97919 0.807711 1.3934 1.3935C0.807612 1.97928 0.807612 2.92903 1.3934 3.51482L10.9393 13.0608ZM10.5 12L10.5 12.0001L13.5 12.0001L13.5 12L10.5 12Z" fill="black"/>
        </svg>
        <p class="faq-answer">- С любыми</p>  
    </div>
</div>

My Js code:
document.querySelector(".arrow").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.querySelector(".arrow").classList.toggle("active");
});

I tried to do it through loops, but it didn't give anyone a result, since I don't know jquery well

You'll want to add a delegated event listener on a suitable parent element, check if the click occurred on one of your .arrow elements and toggle the class on that element specifically.
For example


document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const arrow = e.target.closest('.arrow');
  if (arrow) {
    arrow.classList.toggle('active');
  }
});
.active path {
  fill: red !important;
}
<div class="faq-question-container">
    <div class="faq-question">
        <font>С какими формами организаций вы работаете и заключаете договоры?</font>
        <svg class="arrow" width="24" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M10.9393 13.0608C11.5251 13.6465 12.4749 13.6465 13.0607 13.0608L22.6066 3.51482C23.1924 2.92903 23.1924 1.97928 22.6066 1.3935C22.0208 0.807712 21.0711 0.807712 20.4853 1.3935L12 9.87878L3.51472 1.3935C2.92893 0.807711 1.97919 0.807711 1.3934 1.3935C0.807612 1.97928 0.807612 2.92903 1.3934 3.51482L10.9393 13.0608ZM10.5 12L10.5 12.0001L13.5 12.0001L13.5 12L10.5 12Z" fill="black"/>
        </svg>
        <p class="faq-answer">- С любыми</p>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="faq-question-container">
    <div class="faq-question">
        <font>С какими формами организаций вы работаете и заключаете договоры?</font>
        <svg class="arrow" width="24" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M10.9393 13.0608C11.5251 13.6465 12.4749 13.6465 13.0607 13.0608L22.6066 3.51482C23.1924 2.92903 23.1924 1.97928 22.6066 1.3935C22.0208 0.807712 21.0711 0.807712 20.4853 1.3935L12 9.87878L3.51472 1.3935C2.92893 0.807711 1.97919 0.807711 1.3934 1.3935C0.807612 1.97928 0.807612 2.92903 1.3934 3.51482L10.9393 13.0608ZM10.5 12L10.5 12.0001L13.5 12.0001L13.5 12L10.5 12Z" fill="black"/>
        </svg>
        <p class="faq-answer">- С любыми</p>  
    </div>
</div>



